# jquery onclick add z-index, undo the last element again

Tags: jquery, z-index

I have the following script found here. with the increase in I click the z-index.
But now I want that the last element is restored to the original state. does it somehow?

http://jsfiddle.net/dd5Wp/1/

```
$(function () {
    /*$("div.box").click(function() {
        console.log("start");

    })*/
    // Change this selector to find whatever your 'boxes' are
    var boxes = $("div.box");
    // Set up click handlers for each box
    boxes.click(function () {
        var el = $(this), // The box that was clicked
            max = 0;
        // Find the highest z-index
        boxes.each(function () {
            // Find the current z-index value
            var z = parseInt($(this).css("z-index"), 10);
            // Keep either the current max, or the current z-index, whichever is higher
            max = Math.max(max, z);
        });
        // Set the box that was clicked to the highest z-index plus one
        el.css("z-index", max + 1);
        /* hide and show the content*/
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: What do you mean by 'last element' and 'original state'?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dd5Wp/2/

Comment: I have six pictures, the first has the z-index 10, the second the z-index 9, etc.
when I click it the second picture is increasing its z-index to 11. Now I click on the third image, then would the z-index of 2 original picture worth going back to his back. I hope you understand, my english is not very good

Comment: @herrsaidy Your recently accepted answer is with bugs, Just go to the link provided by him and directly click on the third image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood correctly, each image should go back to the original `z-index` once another image is clicked..

Have a look here, maybe it's what yo need: http://jsfiddle.net/dd5Wp/1/

**CODE**

```
boxes.click(function() {
    var el = $(this), 
        max = 0;

    boxes.each(function() {

        //--- If a previous state is found, restore it
        if($(this).data("original-index")){
            $(this).css("z-index", $(this).data("original-index"));
        }
        var z = parseInt( $( this ).css( "z-index" ), 10 );
        max = Math.max( max, z );
    });

    //--- save the clicked element previous z-index
    el.data("original-index", el.css("z-index"));
    el.css("z-index", max + 1 );
});
```

ps: the "click behaviour" is not working very well because the div wrapping the image (that holds the click behaviour) is bigger than the image itself

Answer (score 0):

I just worked on your case and finally found a solution, Your case is actually in need of a pyramidal approach. Just consider that, the clicked element should be the top piece of the pyramid.

like this:

```
     ----   Clicked element (Assume that it should have z-index 4) 
  ----  ----  (Assume that it should have z-index 3) 
 ----    ----  (Assume that it should have z-index 2)
----      ----  (Assume that it should have z-index 1)
```

So in order to achieve that, I just used [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) to get the left pieces and [nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to get the right pieces. And after that I just traversed through them and assigned z-index by decrementing from the top z-index.

```
$(function() {

    var boxes = $("div.box");
    var boxesLength = $("div.box").length;
    var count;

    boxes.click(function() {            

        var el = $(this);
        el.css("z-index", boxesLength);

        count = boxesLength -1;
        el.prevAll(".box").each(function(){
             $(this).css("z-index", count);
             count -= 1;
        });

        count = boxesLength -1;
        el.nextAll(".box").each(function(){
             $(this).css("z-index", count);
             count -= 1;
        });

    });
});
```

### [LIVE - DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dd5Wp/10/)